# jQuery click open one dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a site I have several 'dropdown' which become visible when you press a plus sign. I did this with jQuery (see code below), but when pressing the button every dorpdown opens. How can I only open the dropdown where the button is pressed (Without writing this code for every button over again)?

```
 $('main .menu').click(function() {

      if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
           $('main .menu').html('&#43;');
           $('main .info').slideUp();

       }
       else {
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $('main .menu').html('&#45;');
            $('main .info').slideDown();

       } 

 });
```

html:

```
<div id="first">
          <img src="images/flexit.jpg" alt="">
          <h2>Flexit</h2>
          <a href="#" class="menu">&#43;</a>
          <div class="info">
               <table>
                    <tr>
                         <td>Name:</td>
                         <td>Flexit</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>Dimensions:</td>
                         <td>2000 x 1600 x 1900 mm</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>Material(s):</td>
                         <td>powdercoated steal, redwood</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>Weight:</td>
                         <td>43 kg</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>Current location:</td>
                         <td>Buzzkruit exhibition, Designcenter Winkelhaak Antwerp</td>
                    </tr>

               </table>          
          </div>
```

Comment: Share your HTML code as well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar added the html!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry for coming back at this. But would there also be a quick way to hide every other dropdown that is open?

Comment: @user3071261 Use `$(".open").removeClass("open");`

Comment: @PraveenKumar When I do this, the classes will only open but not close when pressing again on '.menu-trigger'

Comment: That's the code for closing buddy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep the plus before the menu:

```
<a href="#" class="menu-trigger">+</a>
<ul class="menu">
  <!-- Menu -->
</ul>
<a href="#" class="menu-trigger">+</a>
<ul class="menu">
  <!-- Menu -->
</ul>
```

And in the jQuery, you need to give only for the plus, you can also make the plus as minus:

```
$(".menu-trigger").click(function () {
  $(this).next(".menu").toggleClass("open"); // Selects only the next one!
});
```

Check out the snippet here:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".menu-trigger").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".menu").toggleClass("open"); // Selects only the next one!
    $(this).html($(this).next(".menu").hasClass("open") ? '-' : '+');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-trigger {display: block; width: 3em; text-decoration: none;}
.menu {display: none;}
.menu.open {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="menu-trigger">+</a>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 1</li>
  <li>Menu 1</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="menu-trigger">+</a>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
  <li>Menu 2</li>
</ul>
```